# Monotouch : UIPicker as first responder for a UITextbox

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to implement a UIPicker as custom 'edit' input for the contents of a UITextField.

So far i have this :

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
 // ... snip

    tb_status.EditingDidBegin += delegate {
        //prevent keyboard from popping up
        tb_status.ResignFirstResponder();

        TogglePDCASelect();
    };

    tb_status.ShouldReturn = (textField) => {
        TogglePDCASelect();
        textField.ResignFirstResponder();
        return true;
    };
 // ... snip

    private void TogglePDCASelect()
    {
            pc_PDCAPicker.Hidden = !pc_PDCAPicker.Hidden;
            if(pc_PDCAPicker.Hidden)
        {
                        //AccomodateResponder accomodates the UIScrollView `vwDetails` so that there is room for the responder
                        //and recalculates the scroll content size.
                        //deaccomodate does the reverse.
                scrollViewer.DeAccomodateResponder(vwDetails);
        } 
        else 
        {
            scrollViewer.AccomodateResponder(vwDetails, tb_status.Frame);
        }
    }
```

So far, so good, but when i tap the textbox that calls the picker, and then tap a normal text field or switch the vwDetails subview, the picker stays in view.

It seems like a lot of pain to set it up like this.
Am i doing it wrong? is there any way i can get the picker to behave just like the default firstresponder (keyboard)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you essentially want to use a custom keyboard/input for that particular textfield?

You can override that `UITextField`'s `InputView` with your own custom `UIView` and it will show that instead of the keyboard when it becomes first responder.

**EDIT**

Your picker's `InputView` is going to be null so thats why that didn't work. You need to create a new `UIView` and assign that to the `tb_status`'s `InputView`. So if you add your picker to this view then it should display your picker.

A simple code sample: (I haven't got the time to verify this is 100% correct but should get you on your way)

```
...// snip
UIView pickerView = new UIView(new RectangleF(0,0,320,216));
pickerView.AddSubview(pc_PDCAPicker);
tb_status.InputView = pickerView;
```

Comment: seriously? (that would make me really happy) i'm going to try this again. hang on.

Comment: i'm currently setting the inputview like this : `tb_status.InputView = pc_PDCAPicker.InputView;` but no cigar. (`pc_PDCAPicker` is a `UIPicker`)

Comment: ah so i was messing up with using the pc_PDCAPicker.InputView.
You sir, just made my day. many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your view is 320 x 480. So Initially your picker should have frame as x, 320, width, height.

Now, when user edits the text field, animate the picker frame to some visible height using UIView animation as follows.

```
-(void) presentPickerView{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];

CGRect viewFrame = self.pickerView.frame;

viewFrame.origin.y -= self.pickerView.bounds.size.height;

self.pickerView.frame = viewFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

```
-(void) dismissPickerView {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];

CGRect viewFrame = self.pickerView.frame;

viewFrame.origin.y += self.pickerView.bounds.size.height;

self.pickerView.frame = viewFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

You don't need to see the keyboard when you edit this textField, so return NO here.

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if ([textField isEqual:myTextField]) {
    [self presentPickerView];
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

}

Animate the picker down when text field editing is done.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if ([textField isEqual:myTextField]) {
    // Animate picker down back again.
    [self dismissPickerView];
}
```

}

Comment: Got me a little closer, but not quite there yet :(
There is no `textFieldDidEndEditing` in MonoTouch.
There *is* an `objectDidEndEditing` but it seems to be different enough to be of no help here

Comment: You just need to present the picker when your text field (or object in mono touch) starts editing (check for object comparison in monotouch's objectDidBeginEditing (you can say here resignFirstResponder for your text field so that keyboard doesnt pop's up like, [textField resignFirstResponder]). And dismiss the picker in objectdidEndEditing.

Comment: Even though i could get this to work, it makes a mess of the subview i need to resize to accomodate the subView, making the above answer's method much cleaner. +1 for the effort.